# There are no icons in complications on Pixel Watch and in the api30 emulator

Tags: java, wear-os, android-wear-complication, android-wear-3.0

On api less than 30 everything works, on Samsung (GW4) watches with api30 icons are also normally displayed and you can pull them out of ComplicationData.

```
if (complicationData.getIcon()!=null) {
    icon[complicationId] = complicationData.getIcon();
    drawable = icon[complicationId].loadDrawable(getApplicationContext());
}
```

And in Pixel Watch and the emulator with api30 we have an error:

`Unable to find pkg=com.google.android.wearable.sysui for icon Icon(typ=RESOURCE pkg=com.google.android.wearable.sysui id=0x7f08010a)`
`android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.google.android.wearable.sysui`

The same (nothing data received) with

```
.getSmallImage() .getLargeImage() .getBurnInProtectionIcon()
```

Moreover, if you run the watchface from the Samsung Studio on the same emulator, there are icons.

But the text from complications is displayed allways normally and is pulled out without problems.

Something new in api 30 that is not shown in the complications documentation.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without switching to a jetpack?